# why does the conversion of two elements from a string, from char to int, not add togeather?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, type-conversion

The string input is any size, the nth element in the string must be subtracted from the nth+1 element, but i get large numbers as the conversion from char to int does not work. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *inputString(FILE* fp, size_t size){
char *str;
int ch;
size_t len = 0; 
str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
if(!str)return str;
while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n')
{
    str[len++]=ch;
    if(len==size)
    {
        str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));
        if(!str)return str;
    }
}
str[len++]='\0';

return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

int main(void){
char *m;

printf("input string :");
m = inputString(stdin, 10);

int i;
int dif;
int x;
int y;

for (i=0; i<strlen(m);i++)
{
    x = m[i+1] - '0';
    y = m[i] - '0';
    dif = x - y;
    printf("%d__",&dif);
}

free(m);
return 0;
}
```

the input could be a string '123' and the output should be:

1__1__

but is

1573526312__1573526312__1573526312__

What is wrong with the conversion and why wont til add togeater as expected?

Comment: `printf("%d__",&dif);` --> `printf("%d__", dif);`, Also `i<strlen(m)` --> `i<strlen(m)-1`

Comment: `return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);` --> `return str;`

Comment: The variable `dif` is an integer... So, in the `print()` function, remove the `&` before to display its value instead of its address.

Comment: @M.M Why? What's wrong with `return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);`?

Comment: @RadLexus Sorry. I don't get you. I don't see what's obsolete there. "_last line makes sure there is an uninitialized byte at the end_" - Doesn't it correctly re-allocate the required number of bytes the string needs exactly? I don't see an uninitialized byte at the end...

Comment: @CoolGuy: ha. ... Fortunately, after writing a longish comment explaining why, I checked my statements against OPs code. You are right - that last line is to *shrink* the allocated memory. I guess I mentally inserted `size` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at it again and realized im calling the address of dif and not dif, this is the problem.